# Recommendation for a Macbook Pro M1 Pro/Max docking station

Tags: docking-stations, macbook

There are countless USB C and Thunderbolt docking stations out there. But it's kinda difficult to buy one that really works.

I have one of the new 14" MacBook Pro M1 Max which are capable to natively support up to four external displays without any workarounds like DisplayLink.

I'm looking for a compatible / working docking station that has:

- 2x video ports (HDMI or DisplayPort), my existing displays do not support USB C or Thunderbolt
- Some USB A 3.1 Gen2 (10Gbps)
- Some USB C 3.1 Gen2 (10Gbps) and / or Thunderbolt ports
- Optional one or two low speed USB A 2.0

I prefer a good Thunderbolt 3 docking station over a Thunderbolt 4 that is sensitive to errors. Some of the newer TB4 docking stations doesn't have a HDMI/DisplayPort connector at all. What are your experiences with TB4 connectors and a Thunderbolt <-> HDMI